# Post to a php page using angularjs but return the html code not data

Tags: php, html, angularjs

This is my code:

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['uiSlider']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$http) {

  $scope.change=function(){
      $http.post('index.php',{'oTime':'0'})
                    .success(function(data){
                        $scope.r=data;
  })
  };
```

php:

```
   <?php

if(isset($_POST['oTime']) or isset($_POST['oTimeZone']))
{
    echo "this is the return ";    die();
}
?>
<html ng-app="plunker">

.... <p>{{r}}</p>

</html>
```

I was hopping r will be 0
but it turned out to be "`<html ng_app>.....</html>`"

Could not finger out what is happening.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should `encode` your data first. Just use

```
$str = "this is the return ";
echo json_encode($str);
die();
```

And you should use `data-ng-controller` directive in your HTML.

```
<html data-ng-app="plunker" data-ng-controller="MainCtrl">
```